# SQL query in Excel locking table?

Tags: sql-server, excel

I ran into an issue where no queries could be executed at all against a single table in our database. The table was in a complete deadlock. I checked `sp_whoisactive` for answers and found the following.

[image: Results of sp_whoisactive]

A simple `SELECT` on this table with session id 172, was waiting for a `DELETE` query on this table with session id 478, which was waiting for an `INDEX REORGANIZE` on this table with session id 207, which was waiting for a simple `SELECT` on this table with session id 598.

After killing session 598 everything completed immediately. Afterwards, executing that same query that was keeping the table in a deadlock in a separate window in SSMS only took 2 seconds. I asked around and this query is executed by an Excel file. Apparently we have lots of Excel files floating around which run queries against our SQL database. Obviously this is extremely bad practice as the connection string can be found inside, but as with everything legacy that's just the way it is now until it is fixed.

When googling I'm finding a [lot](https://www.reddit.com/r/MSAccess/comments/2kplf9/database_lock_appears_when_connecting_to_data_via/) [of](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/8dcd524b-4831-4e2f-9731-43a1500a414b/how-to-prevent-access-locking-records-in-sql-server-with-pass-through-query?forum=accessdev) [resources](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/28412a74-0690-4e25-a32c-7a73c2a26eb0/best-practice-connecting-to-sql-server-from-excel?forum=sqldatamining) [about](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/2fab026f-16d0-443e-a447-4a544a26269e/will-a-read-only-query-in-excel-lock-the-records-in-ms-sql-server-2005-database?forum=sqldataaccess) [Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/455365/can-an-excel-data-connection-lock-a-db-table) actually locking tables. Now as far as my limited understanding of locks goes if the query executed by session id 598 would actually lock the table it should only do so for the duration of the query. And since running the query separately only took a few seconds I don't understand how it was running for over 12 hours. If I can trust the results of `sp_whoisactive` it wasn't waiting on anything else. So why didn't it complete?

Before I suggest something like adding `WITH(NOLOCK)` to every query in Excel files, which is just a patch and not a solution I'd like to find out why this happened so that we can avoid this in the future. What causes a deadlock like this and how can it be avoided?

Answer (score 0):

Excel will do a page lock for the duration of the query and until the query is released, which is basically when the spreadsheet is closed.  So, if the spreadsheet was left open by a user overnight or for an entire day, then the table would be locked.  We have the same issue and we are trying to get the offending spreadsheets replaced with SSRS reports but not having much luck with the take up from staff because the Excel files do a lot of other things that SSRS doesn't.